# How do I make this 'p' variant from the font eurm10?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

The AMS fonts package provides the font `eurm10` (see page 32 of [this PDF](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf)) which has two `p` characters. In the font table, they are at positions 70 and 7D. The second one looks a bit like `\wp` but less loopy and IMO more readable. But ... I can't for the life of me figure out how to get just that one character (7D) from that font. I want to use `computer modern` for all of the math except for that one character as say `\varp`. How do I use that character?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have taken the liberty of doing minor cosmetic edits to your post, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, @Corentin. As you can tell, this is my first TeX.SX post and I wasn't aware of community's conventions.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "7D symbol *is* the \wp symbol (as designed in the euler font). I am unsure whether you want to replace the math letter p by this symbol (a strange idea IMHO) or to define a variant to the math letter p or to replace the cm \wp by the euler one or to have a variant of the cm \wp.

The code below could help you anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{euletters}{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{euletters}{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}
%% uncomment the line below if you want a \varwp variant for the \wp symbol
%%\DeclareMathSymbol{\varwp}{\mathord}{euletters}{"7D}
%% uncomment the line below if you want to replace the \wp symbol by the euclid one
%%\DeclareMathSymbol{\wp}{\mathord}{euletters}{"7D}
%% comment the line below if you want to replace the math letter p by the euler \wp symbol (strange idea!)
\DeclareMathSymbol{p}{\mathalpha}{euletters}{"7D}
%% uncomment the line below if you want a \varp variant for the math letter p.
%%\DeclareMathSymbol{\varp}{\mathalpha}{euletters}{"7D}

\begin{document}
    $\wp \neq p$
    {\boldmath $\wp \neq p$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A million thanks! How can I tell that the table for `eurm10` corresponds to `...{U}{eur}{m}{n}`?

For the record, your `\varwp` was the use case I wanted—just to use that symbol, not to change `\wp` or `p`.

Comment: Information about eurm10 and the \DeclareSymbolFont statement could be found in $TEXMF/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueur.fd file.